# How to detect touches on UIImageView of UITableViewCell object in the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle style

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I am using the `UITableViewCell` object in the [`UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)
 style (i.e an image view on the left, text label in bold and under that a detail text label) to create my table. Now I need to detect touches on the `UIImageView` and also to know the indexpath/cell in which the image view was clicked. I tried using

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Sometext";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"emptystar1" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
cell.imageView.image = theImage;
cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

But it's not working. Whenever the image is clicked, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called. I don't want to create a separate `UITableViewCell` and add a custom button to it. Is there any way to detect touches on the `UIImageView` itself?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method add this code

```
cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];   
[tapped release];
```

And then to check which `imageView` was clicked, check the flag in `selector` method

```
-(void)myFunction :(id) sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);
}
```

Comment: This is broken in iOS 5.0 (maybe 5.0.1 too). See answer by @Andrew

Comment: Using a UILabel instead of a UIImageView and this works in iOS 5.1

Comment: Setting the tag on the imageView will set the same value for all cells, so if there are 10 cells displayed, they'll all get the tag value 9 set (counting from zero)

Comment: Great trick with sending indexPath.row with the tag.  Works like a charm

Answer (score 18):

The accepted solution is currently **broken in iOS 5.0**. The bug causes the image view's gesture recognizer to never be triggered. Through research on the official developer forums I found that **this is a known bug in iOS 5.0**. It is caused by an internal implementation that causes `-gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` to return **NO**.  The bug appears when you are setting the gesture recognizer's delegate to the custom `UITableViewCell` subclass itself.

The **fix** is to override `-gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` in the gesture recognizer's delegate and return **YES**.  This bug should be fixed in a future version of iOS 5.x. This is only safe as long as you are not using the new UITableViewCell copy/paste API's.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch! So is the fix to provide a delegate to the gesture recognizer, give it a `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` method, and return `YES`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, exactly. It must be noted that this is safe as long as you are not using the new cell copy and paste API's.

Comment: I've implemented this method and set the delegate to self, but nothing ever fires. Does anyone know what the status of this issue is in iOS 5.1?

Answer (score 15):

For Swift, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method add this code

```
cell.imageView?.userInteractionEnabled = true
cell.imageView?.tag = indexPath.row

var tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TappedOnImage:")
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
cell.imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
```

And then to check which imageView was clicked, check the flag in selector method

```
func TappedOnImage(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    println(sender.view?.tag)
}
```

Comment: This ended up being the trick for me. User interaction was disabled for me. Thanks for ending hours of debugging =)

Answer (score 6):

One way you could do it is by creating a UIImageView from your image and add a gesture recognizer to it. See the example below

```
//Create ImageView
UIImageView *theImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptystar1.png"]];
theImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

//Add Gesture Recognizer
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelectedInTable)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[theImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
[cell addSubview:theImageView];

//Memory Cleanup
[tapped release];
[theImageView release];

-(void)imageSelectedInTable
{
    NSLog(@"Selected an Image");
}
```

However, you'll now have to layout your cells more since you can't simply use the `UIImageView` property of the `UITableViewCell` since it's readonly.

Comment: Attaching the gesture recognizer to `cell.imageView` should work. Readonly `imageView` doesn't mean that methods can't be called on it.

Comment: Thanx aahrens.. It works fine.. :) The only issue I am facing right now is knowing which image has been selected. Is there any way to send arguments to @selector(imageSelectedInTable:)?? I checked the "id" using colon, but its UITapGestureRecognizer object. I need the indexpath in which the imageview is present. When I tried @selector(imageSelectedInTable:indexPath) the app crashed..

Comment: It works!! I just forgot to add "imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;"

Answer (score 2):

Only how additional information, in my case I had to answer to a tap gesture over an image file of a table cell retrieved from NSFetchedResultsController, so we need the indexPath, not the row, so I decided to use the image tapped itself instead of the row information. I defined a variable for the image:

```
var imgSelected: UIImageView? = nil
```

I added the gesture recognizer to the imageView (imgZona):

```
public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ZonasTableViewCell
    let zona = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Zona

    cell.infoZona = zona

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))

    cell.imgZona?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    cell.imgZona?.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return cell
}
```

and in the "imageTapped" method I retrieved the image and saved to the variable "imgSelected":

```
func imageTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    imgSelected = sender.view as? UIImageView
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MuestraImagen", sender: self)
}
```

Finally, in the "prepareForSegue" method I sent the image of the viewController dedicate to show the image tapped:

```
override public func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
        case "MuestraImagen":
            if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? MuestraImagenViewController {
                if imgSelected != nil {
                    if let img = imgSelected!.image {
                        vc.imgPuente = img
                    }
                }
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is:

- Add ImageView into TableViewCell
- Event click into ImageView different than event click into TableViewCell

--> The below codes work correctly with me:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.png"];
[cell.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];    
[cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and "singleTapGestureCaptured" function

```
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
    NSLog(@"Left Image clicked");
}
```