# iPhone - Detect touches on subview of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am populating a UITableView with cells containing a UIImageView subview. I would like to detect touches on the image view, so I am also adding a gesture recognizer to it. However, nothing is getting called. Here is my code:

```
UIImageView *delete = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 8.0, 33.0, 33.0)];
delete.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete.png"];
delete.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
delete.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

UIGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(deleteTapped)];
gesture.delegate = self;

[delete addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
[self.cellView addSubview:delete];
```

Note: I am technically adding the image view to a container which is then added to the the cell itself, hence `[self.cellView addSubview:delete]`. But I have had the same results adding the image view to the cell directly.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924213/676001) answer on a similar post this is a known bug in iOS 5.0; the solution is to override a delegate method to force the gesture recognizer to begin:

> The fix is to override -gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: in the gesture recognizer's delegate and return YES. This bug should be fixed in a future version of iOS 5.x. This is only safe as long as you are not using the new UITableViewCell copy/paste API's.

I've tried this, but the delegate method never gets called. I've set the `delegate` property (see above) and implemented `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"gesture delegate method called");
    return YES;
}
```

Does any one have an idea why this still wouldn't be working? Or perhaps what this status of this bug is in iOS 5.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to return YES for this delegate methode `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;`

and if you want to detect the tap action use `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: +1, `UIGestureRecognizer` is an abstract base class, and does not recognize any gestures. You need to use one of its subclasses. (see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)