# UIGestureRecognizer handle touches in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, didselectrowatindexpath

I have an `UITableView` in my class with a custom `UITableViewCell` with an `UIImageView` inside.

I need to detect the touch on this `UIImageView` to handle a custom method(`handleSingleTouch:`)
and I need to call the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` when the cell is selected.

So i added a `UIGestureRecognizer` to my `TableView` in this way:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *GEST=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTouch:)];

[self.myTable addGestureRecognizer:GEST];
GEST.delegate=self;
[GEST release];

[GEST setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
[GEST setDelaysTouchesEnded:NO];
```

There is the conflict:
every time the `UIImageView` is touched the `tableview` the `GestureRecognizer` start the method but also the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called.

Someone know the way to call the `gestureRecognizerMethod` without call the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the gesture recognizer to the image rather than the table. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7760402

Comment: this could be a nice and pratic solution..but what about performance and saving memory if u have N items to load??!

Comment: @Denis - Sorry for the *very* late reply. Performance and memory should not be an issue as the views are recycled, and therefore this setup only happens the first time(if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do that, as you need to be touch responsive in the whole cell. But what you can do is `tag` your `UIImageView` and then check at the beginning of -`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, for that `UIImageView` and `return`.

Comment: tnx for ur quick answare! tnx to you i found a grose solution but it works! Every time i detect the touch on UIImageView with a specific tag i set a BOOL isImagePressed to YES and i put the condition if( ! isImagePressed) on didSelectRowAtIndexPath in order to control the specific method.

Comment: someOne else have a more clean solution?