# How to detect touches on UIImageView of UITableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: swift

Basically, it is the same question as this : 
[How to detect touches on UIImageView of UITableViewCell object in the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712161/how-to-detect-touches-on-uiimageview-of-uitableviewcell-object-in-the-uitablevie)

But i have to do it in Swift. I can't program in Obejctive-C.

```
cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];   
[tapped release];


-(void)myFunction :(id) sender
{
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);
}
```

Can somebody help me to port this code ? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try writing it yourself.  That is how you learn.  Here are some line by line hints:

```
1: cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
2: cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;

3: UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myFunction:)];
4: tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
5: [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
6: [tapped release];


7: -(void)myFunction :(id) sender
8: {
9:     UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
10:    NSLog(@"Tag = %d", gesture.view.tag);
11:}
```

Hints

- Lose the semicolons all around
- Line 1) Swift uses `true` instead of `YES` for a positive `Boolean`
- Line 3) Type `let tapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(` into Xcode and look at the choices that pop up for autocomplete.  Chose the one with `target` and `action`.  Fill in target `self` and action `"myFunction:"`
- Line 4) Pretty much identical
- Line 5) Call `addGestureRecognizer(tapped)` on `cell.imageView`
- Line 6) Not needed, ARC does this for you
- Line 7) Define a function `myFunction` that takes a `UITapGestureRecognizer` called `gesture` and doesn't return anything
- Line 9) Line not needed since you already took care of that in the header of your function
- Line 10) Use `println` instead of `NSLog` and use string interpolation to print out `gesture.view.tag`

Comment: beautiful! finally got rid of custom UIButton over my UIImage :) many thanks mate, works fine in iOS 11 / Swift 4 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

```
cell.imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row

let tapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myFunction))
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
cell.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)



func myFunction(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("it worked")
}
```