# How to get which element received selection in UITableView cell select?

Tags: ios, swift

How to get the tap received element in a cell did select method of a UITableView?

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var eventImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentTitleView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
}

class SampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    // ..
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // how to check if the tap was on eventImageView when the cell got tapped or on a label or on any other UI element? 
    }
}
```

What I am looking of is something analogous to `event.target` in JavaScript which gives which UI element the user tapped on, instead of keeping track of every UI element in an array.

Comment: Hello, Please Update your code with a Array Which You Pass And Which Page You Have to Navigate

Comment: I don't have to navigate to any page. I need to check if image did receive a tap when the cell got selected. Which array are you referring to?

Comment: just grab cell with cellForRow method of tableview and check eventImageView.image is nil or not

Comment: @Dharmesh Kheni This is not a duplicate of the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106043/how-to-detect-touches-on-uiimageview-of-uitableviewcell-in-swift which uses `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya: That would lead to issues when the cell is reused. Let's say it is a `UILabel` instead with value which is not `nil`.

Comment: @jsloop What you need is to use data source array !!  If you are using array of struct then create one property there of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/) provides a solution.
The basic idea is that you override `hitTest:withEvent:` in `MyCell`, which is a subclass of a `UIView`.
This function computes the topmost touched subview in your `tableViewCell`, which is what you need.
But then, your implementation of `hitTest:withEvent:` should return `nil`, which forwards the touch to the `tableViewCell` that calls then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
One requirement to work is that you set `userInteractionEnabled` of your subviews inside your cell to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here I don't mention cellForRow and numberOfRow Method But in didselect method this way you can get your selected image Hope it helps you   

     class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
            @IBOutlet weak var eventImageView: UIImageView!
        }

        class SampleTableViewController: UITableViewController {
            var arrImages = [UIImage]()

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                arrImages = ["passyourimages"]
            }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

                arrImages[indexPath.row] // Here you get your selected image 
// indexPath.row giving you index of selected cell and that index will be your array index and you got your selected image here !!

            }
        }
```

Comment: Never use `dequeueReusableCell` outside cellForRow method it will create problem. You must use cellForRow instead

Comment: I didn't downvote it. I never do downvote without comment a valid reason

Comment: @jsloop okay checking

Comment: Same way you just have to do a array of images and array of string that's it or using model too you can solved this got ?