# Do some thing when press UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I created table view in `UIViewController`, and successfully created cells, but I could not figure out how to do something when press any cell. I want if press one cell, go to another view controller. I added some methods but did not work. What methods should I add and how to connect the method with action?

This method is for create Array

```
-(void)addCell{

    int wholeNumber = 500;
    int leftOver = wholeNumber%90;
    int sectionNumber = wholeNumber / 90;;

    tableTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    tableSubtitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i =1; i<= sectionNumber; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"90 Questions. Free."];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];


        }else if (i==2){
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"90 Questions. Unlock or Rate App."];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];
        }else if (i==3){
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"90 Questions. Unlock or Sign in and rate 15 questions."];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];
        }else if (i==4){
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"90 Questions. Unlock or Sign in and write explanation for 4 questions."];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];
        }else if (i>4){
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"90 Questions. Unlock or Sign in and contribute 2 questions."];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];
        }else{

        }




    }
    if (leftOver == 0) {


    } else {
        if (sectionNumber == 0) {
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];

            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Questions. Free.",leftOver];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];
        }else if (sectionNumber==1){
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];

            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Questions. Unlock or Rate app.",leftOver];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];
        }else if (sectionNumber==2){
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"];

            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Questions. Unlock or Sign in and rate 15 questions.",leftOver];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];
        }else if (sectionNumber==3){
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"4"];

            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Questions. Unlock or Sign in and write explanation for 3 questions.",leftOver];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];
        }else if (sectionNumber>3){
            NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sectionNumber +1];

            NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Questions. Unlock or Sign in and contribute 1 questions.",leftOver];
            [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
            [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];
        }else {

        }

    }

    NSString *stringForTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CQ"];
    NSString *stringForsubitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Contribute Questions."];
    [tableTitle addObject:stringForTitle];
    [tableSubtitle addObject:stringForsubitle];




}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableTitle count];
}
```

This method Creates Cell

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thisCell"];



    UILabel *titleLable= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 4, 60, 40)];
    titleLable.text = [tableTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [titleLable setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:25]];
    titleLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleLable.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    CALayer* layer = [titleLable layer];
    CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    bottomBorder.borderWidth = 1;
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(-1, layer.frame.size.height-1, layer.frame.size.width, 1);
    [bottomBorder setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
    [layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLable];
    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat actualwidth = width - 100;


    UILabel *subtitleLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 4, actualwidth, 40)];
    subtitleLable.text = [tableSubtitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    subtitleLable.numberOfLines = 0;

    [subtitleLable setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
    subtitleLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    CALayer* layer2 = [subtitleLable layer];
    CALayer *bottomBorder2 = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder2.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    bottomBorder2.borderWidth = 1;
    bottomBorder2.frame = CGRectMake(-1, layer2.frame.size.height-1, layer2.frame.size.width, 1);
    [bottomBorder2 setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
    [layer2 addSublayer:bottomBorder2];



    [cell.contentView addSubview:subtitleLable];


    UILabel *spaceLable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(actualwidth+60, 4, 100, 40)];

    spaceLable.text = @"";
    spaceLable.numberOfLines = 0;

    [spaceLable setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
    spaceLable.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    CALayer* layer3 = [spaceLable layer];
    CALayer *bottomBorder3 = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder3.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    bottomBorder3.borderWidth = 1;
    bottomBorder3.frame = CGRectMake(-1, layer3.frame.size.height-1, layer3.frame.size.width, 1);
    [bottomBorder3 setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
    [layer3 addSublayer:bottomBorder3];


    [cell.contentView addSubview:spaceLable];












    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    rowNo = indexPath.row;
}
```

This is image form Table View

[image]

here is table view delegate connection image.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some option to do it.

1. You already have delegate of tableview itself. Set the delegate like :

   ```
   self.tableView.delegate = self;
   ```

Now implement your delegate when user select any cell.

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

   int ClickedRow = indexPath.row;
  // You can go further with this ID->ClickedRow 

 }
```

2. You can add UIButton to tablecell.

   ```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thisCell"];


     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

     //set the position of the button
    button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + 100, cell.frame.origin.y + 20, 100, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"myButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
     [cell addSubview:button];

    return cell;
    }


     -(void)customActionPressed:(UIButton*)sender
     {

      NSLog(@"%i",[sender tag]); / with this tag, you can do anything..

     }
   ```
3. You can add gesture: Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, do it. You have a imageview or button on tablecell. So add tag to it:

   ```
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
       tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
       tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
       imageView.tag = indexPath.row;

       [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];


      // handle method
    - (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
     {
        //Do anything here ....


        NSLog (@"%d",[gestureRecognizer.view tag]);


         }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, It is worked. I used 3rd one, using gesture recognizer. How do you identify which cell clicking?

Comment: `- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"a");
   
    if (rowNo == 0) {
        NSLog(@"0");
    }
    if (rowNo == 1) {
        NSLog(@"1");
    }
}` I want to add this, so how to Identify which cell am I clicking? in other word how to make `rowNo` here?

Comment: Add a uiimageview to cell and add gesture to it. Updated answer. Check it- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712161/how-to-detect-touches-on-uiimageview-of-uitableviewcell-object-in-the-uitablevie

Comment: Good to know. Carry on.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have already written UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    rowNo = indexPath.row;
}
```

This delegate should work but I think you may have forgot to set the delegate for your UITableView.

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

If you have created tableView using Interface builder then check the UITableView delegate connection

Comment: Thank you very much. where should I add `tableView.delegate = self`? I already added delegate to UITableView, that is why the cell shows. here is link for image. https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqDPUF7IFADqg7oGBWgX3k5XH8CAyA

Comment: Wherever you are creating the tableView, you can add this line 'tableView.delegate=self' next to tableView.datasource=self

Comment: I created this tableView using storyboard. and connect the delegate  and datasource using storyboard. I really could not figure out where is problem.

Comment: My bad, please check when you click the cell, do you get the control in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, if you do get the control there, by putting a breakpoint then that is where you can segue to your new `viewController` or whatever way you want to move to the `NewViewController`

Comment: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
NSLog(@"a");  rowNo = indexPath.row;  (rowN == 0) {  NSLog(@"a");  }}`. I put this, but could not control the method by clicking the cell.